# TRIM data that is imported via IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, trim, array-formulas, importrange

I am importing data from another workbook, but some of the data have extra spaces at the start or end. I am looking for a way to `TRIM` the `IMPORTRANGE` data.

Answer (score 1):

your formula should be like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(IMPORTRANGE("ID"; "SheetName!A1:D20")))
```